# Why doesn't string.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') work with underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a string, `str` with multi-line content in it, and I want to display it correctly on the HTML page with `underscore.js` using the above `replace` mentioned, like so:

```
<%= str.replace(/\n/g , '<br />' %>
```

But that doesn't work at all. It still prints the string in one line, and doesn't replace any `\n` with `<br />`. This, however, works perfectly:

```
<%= str.replace(/
/g , '<br />' %>
```

So why doesn’t the first way work, and is there a way to make it work for all cases?

Comment: Oh sorry @muistooshort , I missed the `=` in this question. However, it is there in my HTML file.

Comment: What is a "string with multi-line content in it"? How is escaping (`\ `) handled in there?

Comment: @Bergi it is a string which when viewed in a general text editor will show content spanning multiple lines(with line breaks in it). But it comes out in a single line on the webpage, because the browser collapses all the white spaces. As for the escaping, I think the `\n` is being removed or modified by something before it reaches javascript interpreter. However, minitech's answer below shows a way to avoid the problem of having to handle newlines and other whitespaces ourselves entirely. You basically tell the browser to take them literally and not ignore them.

Comment: @udiboy1209: Ah, right. What I meant to ask was how the (multiline?) template is stored - as a string inside a script, as a node of an html document?

Comment: @Bergi , I basically stopped looking further into this issue after minitech's answer solved it. If you are curious, you can look at the source code of [web plugin for beets](https://github.com/sampsyo/beets/tree/master/beetsplug/web/templates) on github. The problem I was referring to is in the `index.html` page of that plugin.

Comment: I just was curious why the second version worked. Probably the linebreak is getting escaped automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might need to double-escape backslashes if they’re used as an escape character by your template engine:

```
<% str.replace(/\\n/g , '<br />' %>
```

However, consider instead using CSS:

```css
.some-content {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is a very elegant solution! Thank you.